# java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"

Tags: java, android, http, protocolexception

I want to get data using HTTP GET method.
But response is wrong

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
```

How to fix it?

```
public  JSONArray GetPost_sport(String token, String sport_type){

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://o-two-sport.com/api/posts/?sport_type="+sport_type);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Token " +token);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String inputStr;
        while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
            responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

        jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: the HTTP response is not json str, it return error info by html. you need confirm which type content the HTTP response is when you request is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving a usual HTML page as response, which is not JSON - ready. Find an API of this site to retrieve JSON content type.

I suppose you should add `format=json` to your URL:

```
new URL("http://o-two-sport.com/api/posts/?format=json&sport_type="+sport_type);
```